# React: expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a 3rd party library 'FoamTree' in my react app to make tree visualization. When I import its file 'carrotsearch.foamtree.js' in my component it gives me this error in multiple lines:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

It works fine in normal Javascript. It gives errors only when it is imported in react
There are many lines in that file that give me this error. Few of them I am sharing:

```
this.j = function (m, k) {
      var f = a[m];
      f || (f = [], a[m] = f);
      f.push(k);
    };
```

```
 function m(a) {
      var d = a.O,
          c = a.Sb[0].length - 1;
      a.Ib[c] && (d.setLineDash(a.Ib[c]), d.Uj = a.Ld[c]);
      d.miterLimit = a.Qd[c];
      d.lineWidth = a.Md[c];
      d.shadowBlur = a.ie[c];
      d.shadowOffsetX = a.je[c];
      d.shadowOffsetY = a.ke[c];
      d.font = a.Nc[c].replace("#SIZE#", a.hc[c].toString());

    }
```

```
for (e = 0; e < g; e++) {
       h = c[e].kd, m[h.index] = !0, 0 > r * (h.x - k.x) + s * (h.y - k.y) + l * (h.z - k.z) && a.d(b, h);
}
```

```
 this.kc = function (a, b) {
      D.V(b) || (n[a] = b, m(a));
      return n[a];
 };
```

Edit:
When I change this block:

```
this.kc = function (a, b) {
    D.V(b) || (n[a] = b, m(a));
    return n[a];
};
```

to this:

```
  this.kc = function (a, b) {
      if( D.V(b) || (n[a] = b, m(a)) ){
          return n[a];
      }
  };
```

then the error is gone

Comment: This has nothing to do with React. As a general rule, I usually don’t bother linting third party code. You can create a `.eslintignore` file to disable linting in specific files, directories, and glob patterns.

Comment: @JoelCornett how to create and add .eslintignore in my file structure. Please help me on this

Comment: See here: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The issue got solved by adding this to the top of the file:

```
/* eslint-disable */
```

Comment: You should at least change it to `/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */` or add `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions` above the line where this error happens instead.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the expression causing the issue. But looking at your expression, I think you want to do simply like:

```
a[m] = f || []
```

Instead of:

```
 var f = a[m];
      f || (f = [], a[m] = f);
```

Anyways, `allowShortCircuit` should solve your issue:

```
/*eslint no-unused-expressions: [
  "error", { 
    "allowShortCircuit": true
  }]*/
```

For further configuration, see:

[no unused expression](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions)

Comment: I think there is some issue in the code in the file. It works fine in normal javascript it only gives errors when I import it in react and now when I add return inside the function block, then it does not give me error.

Comment: Did you change the eslint configuration as per my answer?

Comment: yes your code removed the error of that line but the  'eslint' thing did not work

Comment: `but the 'eslint' thing did not work` - what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

That's just a lint error. You can ignore it. The error is on this line :

```
D.V(b) || (n[a] = b, m(a));
```

As you can see it is an expression ( `||` in the middle of two expressions ) and is not an assignment or a function call. You can simply ignore it or rewrite it to remove the expression as a statement and replace it with an if condition or something similar ( whatever serves the same purpose ).